# process has died

Tags: ros, opencv, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I wrote some code . and ran those with launch file . every worked thing fine at the first but after a few minutes I got this msg:

```
[QR_left-2] process has died [pid 9513, exit code -11, cmd /home/hamid/Working_space/Qr/bin/Qr_detection /QR_left/image:=image __name:=QR_left __log:=/home/hamid/.ros/log/f2d341cc-05c7-11e4-9fa2-002682d6e390/QR_left-2.log].
log file: /home/hamid/.ros/log/f2d341cc-05c7-11e4-9fa2-002682d6e390/QR_left-2*.log
```

and the node has stopped.

any idea about the above msgs?

hamid

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185197/process-has-died-../) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-07**:
I think you should either run roslaunch in verbose mode (-v and --screen options) or read the log files to find out why this happened. Or, simply run the node using rosrun.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-07**:
-11 is a segfault. You probably have some bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this message for wifi configuration. Use GDB to get a backtrace of the process to find out why this happened.

---

Originally posted by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) with karma: 70 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0